# Submitting Chinese characters results in numeric character references

Tags: xml, character-encoding, cjk

I am submitting a Chinese character to my form but once it is submitted it is coming as XML numeric character reference.
For e.g. I am entering this `星洲` and the value going to my form is `&#26143;&#27954;`

Any inputs how to convert this XML numeric character reference to the Chinese character equivalent?

Comment: I am entering this ‘星洲’ and the value going to my form is ‘星洲’ ?
There is no difference between two in your question? Can you clarify?

Comment: In the future, use backticks `\`` not singlequotes `'` to format code. Otherwise XML entities are actually parsed into its character representations, resulting in confusions. Oh, the answer depends on the server side programming language you're using since the cause of the problem is likely in there. You would like to add detail/tags about the programming language in question.

Answer (score 0):

The value you are submitting and getting back is same as per Google translator. As far as encoding is concerned you can use UTFEncoding to store and display data in order to avoid corruption.